# How to integrate Pay Later in Magento 2.4.3?

Tags: payment-methods, admin-panel, paypal-express, magento2.4.3, paypal-paylater

Could you Please anyone suggest that how to integrate Pay Later Payment Method in Magento 2.4.2?
I have enabled Pay Later button from the Admin side but Pay Later Button is not showing.

Comment: Have cleared flush cache?did you configured correctly?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

**Important**: Before you configure PayPal Credit or PayPay Pay Later for your store, make sure it is enabled in your PayPal Merchant Account.

Comment: Yes, I have enabled PayPal Credit in Sandbox account but when order place using paypal credit from PDP page than it's every time redirect magento order review page and review step skip set YES. I don't know why this happen if you have any idea than share with me.

Comment: It should not redirect to review step. but if it's still happening then please check any of your 3rd party extension like onestepcheckout or any module is not responsible for that.